# Aspose excel sorting in protected worksheet

Tags: .net, aspose-cells

is it possible a protected worksheet allow sorting?

Allow User to edit range is tried, but the cell inside the range is also editable which is not expected.

Thanks

Comment: so do you mean it is impossible to do sorting in a protected worksheet? i knew excel itself also unable to sort in protected worksheet, i just curious if there is any trick to overcome that, as i do really need to lock the sheet and some fields are editable, but can do sorting for the table.

Comment: Aspose.Cells follows Microsoft Excel standards. If something is possible with Microsoft Excel, it should also be possible with Aspose.Cells. You can however unprotect your worksheet using Aspose.Cells and then do sorting and then again protect it using Aspose.Cells. It should fit your needs. Thanks.

Comment: user is proposed to download an excel template with protection so only some fields can be edited, as it is a table, it is always "nice to have" filter & sorting. in this case i think there is solid restriction and not achievable in excel.

Comment: Please share the template Excel and the modified (expected) Excel file. You can create both of them using Microsoft Excel and attach on Google Drive or Drop Box and share the download link here. Please keep them as simple as possible. We will check both of your files and compare them and see if it is possible to create expected Excel file from template Excel file and share our findings with you. Thanks for your cooperation in this regard and have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Please unprotect the worksheet first, only then you will be able to do sorting. This is also a Microsoft Excel behavior. Please see the warning message of Microsoft Excel in this screenshot for a reference.

**Screenshot:**
[image]

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it, I use to sort mostly in Filter. But Sort button is allowed too.
First set Filter on (maybe optional). Then you need to use "Allow Users to Edit Ranges" and then protect worksheet with filter (maybe optional) and sort enabled.

Here are steps how to do it in Excel:
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4673-excel-sort-filter-protected-sheet.html
or Solution 1 in: http://blog.softartisans.com/2013/10/01/kb-sorting-locked-cells-in-protected-worksheets/

[sort in filter on protected sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqg1H.png)

[sort using sort button on protected sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1eaR.png)

Here is my example in Aspose.Cells for Java (should be similar in .net):

```
    Cells cells = sheet.getCells();
    int maxCol = cells.getMaxDataColumn();
    int maxRow = cells.getMaxDataRow();
    sheet.getAutoFilter().setRange(0, 0, maxCol);
    sheet.getAllowEditRanges().add("allowSortFilter", 0, 0, maxRow, maxCol);
    Protection protection = sheet.getProtection();
    protection.setAllowSelectingLockedCell(false);
    protection.setAllowSelectingUnlockedCell(true);
    protection.setAllowFiltering(true);
    protection.setAllowSorting(true);
    protection.setAllowEditingContent(false);
    protection.setAllowEditingObject(false);
    protection.setAllowEditingScenario(false);
    protection.setPassword("password");
    }
    OoxmlSaveOptions opts = new OoxmlSaveOptions(SaveFormat.XLSX);
```